# Is there an alternative to xp_cmdshell and net use for backing up MSSQL to UNC as a different user

Tags: sql-server, backup, net-use

Is there an alternative to `xp_cmdshell` and `net use` for backing up MSSQL to a UNC with a different user?

I'm now using

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use \\SERVER\SHARE  Password /USER:DOMAIN\USER /PERSISTENT:yes'
```

as a preexec script.

But `xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default (owing to security issues, I'd guess).

Answer (score 2):

For `BACKUP` statements SQL Server will use the service account under which the database engine service is running as the security context for interaction with the operating system.  Therefore you would need to grant the SQL Server service account access to the share.  There's no way around this other than your `xp_cmdshell` hack.

For example:

If the SQL Server service is running as the domain user `MYDOMAIN\SQLUser` then you would need to modify the share permissions to allow access to this user.

If SQL Server is running as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE` then, assuming your SQL Server machine name is `SQLHOST`, you would need to modify the share permissions to allow access to `SQLHOST$`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there aren't other ways for that.

normal TSQL Backup Skripts only allow to backup to local disc.

If you have enough space you could make a SQL-Task which makes a backup on local disk and after this move it via powershell to a UNC path.

if you don't have enought space for this:
with the following you can activate xp_cmdshell again...

```
    -- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE;
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms190693.aspx

Comment: TSQL `BACKUP` allows backup to UNC paths

Comment: Oh ok. I'm very sorry. Did't know that. Saw you post above and did a voteup. So i have learned something today. Thank you!

Comment: one last thought: Maybe you have a chance to use SQL-Server Proxy? see following links: (couldn't test it at the moment) http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1199/sql-server-agent-proxies/ AND http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It's a good thought :)  But backups happen through the database engine which doesn't need a proxy.  In fact, you can't create a proxy for the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a symbolic link that's been created after using net use to put in the appropriate credentials.

```
net use \\SERVER\SHARE  Password /USER:DOMAIN\USER /PERSISTENT:yes
mklink /d \\SERVER\SHARE C:\Mounts\SHARE
```

Then in the script, use C:\Mounts\SHARE as the backup path.